# Как скомпилировать std::string в Android NDK?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

Использую Android Studio 3.0.1, но почему-то Android NDK не компилирует такую распространённую функцию как std::string. Есть выход?

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что вы используете C ++ STL: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

(Перевод с помощью Google Translate. Надеюсь, это будет достаточно.)